# How to upload pdf files and link to them?

Tags: 8, files

I look for a comfortable solution to upload files (pdf) in drupal 8 and link to them (open the link in a new tab).
The link I like to embed in a paragraph or apply to lists.
Something like entity embed (embedded file). But I do not like the output of this solution.

> [image]

e.g. I can't open the file new window
 
e.g. I can't change the title of the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution could be [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module which allows you to upload file/images... through CKeditor interface.

> Features
>
> - Basic file operations: upload, delete
> - Image(jpg, png, gif) operations: resize, create thumbnails, preview
> - Support for private file system
> - Configurable limits for user roles: file size per upload, directory quota, file extensions, and image dimensions
> - Personal or shared folders for users
> - Permissions per directory
> - Ftp-like directory navigation
> - File sorting by name, size, dimensions, date
> - Tabbed interface for file operations
> - Keyboard shortcuts(up, down, insert(or enter), delete, home, end, ctrl+A, R(esize), T(humbnails), U(pload)).
> - Built-in support for inline image/file insertion into textareas
> - Multiple file selection(using ctrl or shift)
> - Ajax file operations
> - Themable layout using tpl files

Comment: Great! Works fine!